# Grails Log4J Exception on startup

Tags: grails, log4j

I started getting the following exception on startup recently:

```
 Error log4j:ERROR setFile(null,false) call failed. 
| Error java.io.FileNotFoundException: /var/log/log4j/log4jEvents.xml (No such file or directory) 
| Error at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method) 
| Error at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:194) 
| Error at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:116) 
| Error at org.apache.log4j.FileAppender.setFile(FileAppender.java:294) 
| Error at org.apache.log4j.FileAppender.activateOptions(FileAppender.java:165) 
| Error at org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter.activate(PropertySetter.java:307) 
| Error at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.parseAppender(DOMConfigurator.java:295) 
| Error at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.findAppenderByName(DOMConfigurator.java:176) 
| Error at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.findAppenderByReference(DOMConfigurator.java:191) 
| Error at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.parseChildrenOfLoggerElement(DOMConfigurator.java:523) 
| Error at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.parseCategory(DOMConfigurator.java:436) 
| Error at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.parse(DOMConfigurator.java:1004) 
| Error at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.doConfigure(DOMConfigurator.java:872) 
| Error at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.doConfigure(DOMConfigurator.java:778) 
| Error at org.apache.log4j.helpers.OptionConverter.selectAndConfigure(OptionConverter.java:526) 
| Error at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.<clinit>(LogManager.java:127) 
| Error at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.configure(PropertyConfigurator.java:415) 
| Error at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) 
| Error at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39) 
| Error at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) 
| Error at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) 
| Error at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.GrailsScriptRunner.initializeLogging(GrailsScriptRunner.java:659) 
| Error at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.GrailsScriptRunner.initializeState(GrailsScriptRunner.java:631) 
| Error at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.GrailsScriptRunner.callPluginOrGrailsScript(GrailsScriptRunner.java:414) 
| Error at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.GrailsScriptRunner.executeCommand(GrailsScriptRunner.java:379) 
| Error at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.GrailsScriptRunner.main(GrailsScriptRunner.java:227) 
| Error at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) 
| Error at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39) 
| Error at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) 
| Error at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) 
| Error at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.GrailsStarter.rootLoader(GrailsStarter.java:236) 
| Error at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.GrailsStarter.main(GrailsStarter.java:264) 
| Error at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) 
| Error at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39) 
| Error at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) 
| Error at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) 
| Error at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
```

It doesn't seem to affect anything, but it is a bit annoying. I'm guessing some plugin or dependency that has been put in recently caused this to start happening, because it wasn't always there. I have not been able to track down what it is that's causing it, so I was hoping that maybe someone here had an idea?

Comment: Does the app have write access to path shown above? /var/log/log4j

Comment: It does not. I don't know where that path is coming from, though. It just started happening, and I can only assume that it's because of some dependency that I added.

Comment: @dmahapatro does this mean that the server needs to be  configured to give the app permission to write to `/var/log` explicitly?